# Weird issue with UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an issue with my UITextView.
Whenever I try to type something the UITextView goes up beyond the frame and I can't seem to do anything. Why is this?

Some screenshots:

when I type in the first word:

[image]

then typing another word, it shifts up and I can't see a thing:

[image]

Some code:

```
 self.messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 30)];
    [self.messageTextView setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
    [self.messageTextView setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
    [self.messageTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:16.0]];
    self.messageTextView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Are you doing anything in the UITextViewDelegate methods? i.e. textDidChange? When you type the new word, are you doing so on a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try, `textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;`

Answer (score 0):

give a bigger height to your frame

self.messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 80)];